# Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy returns error about not finding a container

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write some PowerShell but the cmdlet is returning an error and I don't really understand the cause of it.

the cmdlet is `Get-AdUserResultantPasswordPolicy` used thus:

```
Get-AdUserResultantPasswordPolicy -Identity <redacted>
```

It returns the error (apologies for the redactions)

```
PS C:\> Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy -Identity <redacted>
Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=<redacted>y, CN=Password Settings Container,CN=System,DC=<redacted>,DC=<redacted>,DC=<redacted>,DC=<redacted>' under: '<redacted>'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy -Identity <redacted>
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (CN=<redacted>,DC=<redacted>,DC=<redacted>:String) [Get-ADUserResultantPasswordP
   olicy], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADGetPropertiesCmdletBase:WritePropertiesToOutput,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.C  ommands.GetADUserResultantPasswordPolicy
```

the Password Policy absolutely exists. I have confirmed this with both Active Directory Admin Centre and ADSIEdit

has anybody come across this at all?

Comment: It's hard to tell when you've replaced many different values with the same `<redacted>` label. Is the base DN (the trailing `DC=...,DC=...,DC=...` parts of the DN it says it can't find) the one you expect? Or are you perhaps looking at the wrong domain?

Answer (score 0):

As stated below identity parameter specifies an AD user, not a password policy, so a user should be provided near identity such as:

*Get-ADUserResultantPasswordPolicy -Identity BobKe*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduserresultantpasswordpolicy?view=windowsserver2022-ps

-Identity
Specifies an Active Directory user object by providing one of the following property values. The identifier in parentheses is the LDAP display name for the attribute. The acceptable values for this parameter are:

A distinguished name
A GUID (objectGUID)
Security identifier (objectSid)
SAM account name (sAMAccountName)